# Error merging data.table - encoding warning message

Tags: r, encoding, data.table

I'm trying to merge two `data.table` and getting this error message:

```
> tabelaApoio <- merge(data.table(Geo = iconv(.rop, to = 'UTF8'), Level = 2, key = c('Geo', 'Level')), data.table(Geo = iconv(.bairros, to = 'UTF8'), Level = 3, key = c('Geo', 'Level')))
Warning message:
In bmerge(i <- shallow(i), x, leftcols, rightcols, io <- haskey(i),  :
  A known encoding (latin1 or UTF-8) was detected in a join column.
  data.table compares the bytes currently, so doesn't support *mixed* 
  encodings well; i.e., using both latin1 and UTF-8, or if any unknown 
  encodings are non-ascii and some of those are marked known and others not.
  But if either latin1 or UTF-8 is used exclusively, and all unknown encodings
  are ascii, then the result should be ok. In future we will check for you
  and avoid this warning if everything is ok. The tricky part is doing this
  without impacting performance for ascii-only cases.
> tabelaApoio
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: Geo,Level
```

Ok, I understand the problem: the variables don't have the same encoding. The problem - at least, for me - is that both variables are created inside R, on `.First()` function:

```
function() {
dir <- sprintf('C:/Users/%s/Desktop/Coisas', Sys.info()['user'])
if (file.exists(dir)) { setwd(sprintf('C:/Users/%s/Desktop/Coisas/', Sys.info()['user'])) }
else { warning(sprintf('Não foi possível alterar a pasta de trabalho para %s', dir)) }
assign('.dir', sprintf('%sCoisas/ObservaPOA/', substr(R.home(), 1, 3)), .GlobalEnv)
assign('.bairros', c("Agronomia", "Anchieta", "Arquipélago", "Auxiliadora", "Azenha", "Bela Vista", "Belém Novo", "Belém Velho", "Boa Vista", "Bom Fim", "Bom Jesus", "Camaquã", "Campo Novo", "Cascata", "Cavalhada", 
"Cel Aparício Borges", "Centro Histórico", "Chácara das Pedras", "Chapéu do Sol", "Cidade Baixa", "Cristal", "Cristo Redentor", "Espírito Santo", "Farrapos", "Farroupilha", "Floresta", "Glória", 
"Guarujá", "Higienópolis", "Hípica", "Humaitá", "Independência", "Ipanema", "Jardim Botânico", "Jardim Carvalho", "Jardim do Salso", "Jardim Floresta", "Jardim Isabel", "Jardim Itú", "Jardim Lindóia", 
"Jardim Sabará", "Jardim São Pedro", "Lageado", "Lami", "Lomba do Pinheiro", "Mário Quintana", "Medianeira", "Menino Deus", "Moinhos de Vento", "Mont'Serrat", "Morro Santana", "Navegantes", "Nonoai", "Partenon", 
"Passo D'areia", "Passo das Pedras", "Pedra Redonda", "Petrópolis", "Ponta Grossa", "Praia de Belas", "Restinga", "Rio Branco", "Rubem Berta", "Santa Cecília", "Santa Maria Goretti", "Santa Tereza", "Santana", 
"Santo Antônio", "São Geraldo", "São João", "São José", "São Sebastião", "Sarandi", "Serraria", "Teresópolis", "Três Figueiras", "Tristeza", "Vila Assunção", "Vila Conceição", "Vila Ipiranga", "Vila Jardim", 
"Vila João Pessoa", "Vila Nova"), .GlobalEnv)
assign('.rop', c("Centro", "Centro-Sul", "Cristal", "Cruzeiro", "Eixo-Baltazar", "Extremo-Sul", "Glória", "Humaitá / Navegantes", "Ilhas", "Leste", "Lomba do Pinheiro", "Nordeste", "Noroeste",
"Norte", "Partenon", "Restinga", "Sul"), .GlobalEnv)
lockBinding(".dir", .GlobalEnv)
lockBinding(".bairros", .GlobalEnv)
lockBinding(".rop", .GlobalEnv)
source(sprintf('%sLe bancos.R', .dir))
}
```

So, I have no idea of why this warning message and how to solve it. I tried use `iconv()`, but didn't work :(

Comment: @scribbles worked with `latin1`. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Switched comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `Encoding(data1$geo) <- "latin1"` for the `geo` columns of both tables should work.